# How can I show subtitle under title in single product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using OceanWp and WooCommerce.
I've used Kia subtitle plugin to show subtitle of the product in Archive page and it worked. I'm trying right now to show the subtitle also in single product page under the product title.
I've used this hook but it didn't work

```
function kia_add_subtitle_to_single_product(){
    if( function_exists( 'the_subtitle' ) ) the_subtitle( '<h4 class="subtitle">', '</h4>' );
}
add_action( 'ocean_after_single_product_title', 'kia_add_subtitle_to_single_product', 20 );
```

Any suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: ocean_after_single_product_title this hook is prob for archive. For single product if they dont have custom hook you can use this one woocommerce_single_product_summary where the main title by default is priority 5. Your action should look like this - add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'kia_add_subtitle_to_single_product', 6 ); - You can see the default woocommerce hook order here - https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

Comment: didn't work :((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this hook: `woocommerce_single_product_summary`

I just added a subtitle using ACF with this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_acf_field_output', 5 );

function custom_acf_field_output() {
    global $product;
    $field_value = get_field('custom_field_name', $product->get_id());
    if( $field_value ) {
        echo '<div class="custom-field-output">' . $field_value . '</div>';
    }
}
```